# Is there a way to automatically kill a process that its window has been closed?

Tags: windows, process, gaming, kill

This is for games that are known to not close properly. Like Anthem right now. Like detect if the window is gone, if it is, then kill process.

Comment: Command: `taskkill /f /im your-game-name.exe`

Comment: There are plenty of ways to kill applications. There are also plenty of valid reasons why application executables will continue running for a brief period after the program windows close. So a blanket approach is not the correct solution here. If this is a known issue with Anthem, developers are likely working on a solution and a patch in the future will fix the problem. Until then, a script such as @Biswapriyo suggests will do what you need.

Comment: Yeah, they are probably working on it, there's NO reason for it to run after window is closed no. It's just bad programming and a memory leaks issue most likely. Will that command check if the window is closed tho? And how do I get this to run in the background, schedule, like every 30 seconds or 10 seconds?

Comment: Or when an event is logged, doesn't matter if it tries running the kill, as long as it checks if the window is there so it won't kill it.